# Regex everything but number with two decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a nice challenge for those who like regex; like me. Unfortunately, I cannot figure this one out.

This regex is a reverse match. I need to match everything but a proper amount; like:

**These types need to NOT MATCH:**

0,00
0.00
12314345.7
24234.54
34435,00
34545,43

**These types need to MATCH:**

.00
,87
1e3,67

So everything but a decimal amount with a comma or point needs to match in JavaScript (yes, reverse).

I have made this:

```
([^0-9]+([^\.,]{0,1})+[^0-9]{0,2})
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work properly seeing it passes through multiple comma's or dots and doesn't limit the decimals to a maximum of two.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: If you want you can test on http://www.regexr.com/ That is where the "match" and the "not match" is visible.

Comment: But why would you require it? I suppose making a regex for a valid pattern is fairly straight forward and anything not satisfying that regex is your solution. Or is it just for the sake of a challenge?

Comment: If you can split on a character (say whitespace) then: `s.split(/\s+/).filter(function(v) {return !/^\d+[\.,]\d\d$/.test(v)})` may do the job (i.e. filter out the matches).

Comment: @RobG is asking about the formatted input that the regex should run on. The input format will affect the regex. e.g. Your input was line-by-line values before you've edited your question.

Comment: Both sets of numbers follow the same pattern. I'll be surprised if you can match this without an extremely specific and rigid expression.

Comment: The regex is nessesary for a frontend input box in an app.

Comment: Why `12314345.7` shouldn't match if it has only **one** decimal?

Comment: @Ulugbek: because I don't care about the number of decimals lower then 3. We correct while typing and clear on error. The why should not be important, I just need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!\d+([,.]\d{0,2})?$).*$
```

http://regex101.com/r/jY3tC3

*Note*: This regex needs anchoring. I've anchored between `^` and `$`.

Comment: This is very good! It's almost there. It fails on "1.", "1," but also on "1.55555555".

Comment: And again. I didn't have the \d{0,2}.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Works like it should and matches all the inproper values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(?!(\d+[\.,]\d+)).*$/gm
```

See the updated [**demo here**](http://regex101.com/r/qK5yJ2).

Comment: Hi Onur. Sorry, that one doesnt work. But I can also already tell that its not going to work. You are filtering a-zA-Z whilst I want to filter everything but 0-9.

Comment: Change `[a-z]` to `[\D]` or `[^0-9]` to match any non-digit.

Comment: this is accepted: "aasdd.dd" and this "1e34333.ff". So that is not good. Nice solution though, i like it.

Comment: Fails on these: fff,00
1e34
hufreh
pokrg,ji